# How to use `group_by` on this hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, group-by

I have this hash:

```
@hash = [
  {0=>"1", 1=>"A1", 2=>"something", 3=>"10"}, 
  {0=>"2", 1=>"A1", 2=>"something", 3=>"8"},
  {0=>"3", 1=>"A2", 2=>"something", 3=>"3"},
  {0=>"4", 1=>"A2", 2=>"something", 3=>"13"}
]
```

I need to `group_by` the values in the first column (A1, A2) and then work with the data (for example pick out the lowest value for the item with index 3 for A1 and A2).

```
@hash.each do |item|
  item.each do |item2|
    item2.group_by{ |i| i[1] }.each do |p|
      puts p
    end
  end
end
```

But I still cannot figure out how to access those data. I would be very grateful for an advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
>> grouped = @hash.group_by { |h| h[1] }
>> grouped['A1'] # [{0=>"1", 1=>"A1", 2=>"something", 3=>"10"}, {0=>"2", 1=>"A1", 2=>"something", 3=>"8"}]
>> grouped['A2'] # [{0=>"3", 1=>"A2", 2=>"something", 3=>"3"}, {0=>"4", 1=>"A2", 2=>"something", 3=>"13"}]
```

to get the max or minimum value, try

```
>> grouped['A1'].max_by { |h| h[3].to_i }[3] # 10
>> grouped['A1'].min_by { |h| h[3].to_i }[3] # 8
```

Comment: can the downvoter explain why this was downvoted?

Comment: I don't get it as well. This answer helped me `jvnill`, thank you! Marking that as accepted!

Comment: +1 I'd transform `@hash` before grouping (so all string numbers are converted to integers), but in any case this is the way to go.